# Organic replacement for AI

Tags: science-fiction, artificial-intelligence, genetic-engineering, far-future

I’d like to go into a bit of backstory for my setting before I ask my question.

I want to create a space opera setting that is set nearly 60,000 years in the future. Humanity has developed space faring technology, but it is all biopunk in nature, with living ships, guns, and vehicles.

Humanity once used traditional technology, but they were driven to near extinction by a race of mechanical gods that evolved from advanced AI, and developed a fear of anything mechanical.

True AI was banned in this world as a result, with its creation being punishable by death, but I was wondering something. Since artificial intelligence is so useful in our modern world, would a genetically engineered replacement for it be possible?

Comment: What would you like it to be able to do? How would it be different from a genetically engineered person doing it? If you're talking brain-in-a-vat, then that's a different question.

Comment: An artificial organic intelligence would just be an engineered human.  What capabilities are you expecting AI to have that a human brain wouldn't have?

Comment: You're basically referring to Mentats in Dune universe.

Answer (score 2):

#### Organic AI based on semiconductors can exist

Organic intelligence exists, as mostly acknowledged by humans.
Organic semiconductors exist.
Given that strong AI based upon silicon exists. Therefor strong AI based on organic semiconductors can exist.

### Genetic engineering

#### Modification of existing systems

One path would be the modification of existing systems.
Such as uplifting great apes, parrots, cetaceans, cephalopods etc. Or more likely modification of humans.

#### Creation of new organisms

Another path would be the creation of completely new life forms. The advantage here would be much better control of the final product. However the design and understanding challenges are much larger. In general such a creature would have a body and a brain but more novel forms are possible.

#### tldr

Yes constructed strong AI based upon generically engineered organic hardware is possible. Humans exist.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [Frame Challenge](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609).

**We call the biological replacement for mechanical/electronic AI a "brain."**

Humans have been making a biological replacement for AI since the beginning of humanity — brains. So I'd like you to consider looking at your problem from a different perspective.

Rather than reinventing the wheel (by inventing a new biological brain...), what you really want to do is to have advanced genetic engineering that allows you to use the brains Mother Nature already gives you in abundance to suit your needs.

- Need a simple state controller? Use a rat's brain.
- Need something that can monitor and adjust the environment inside a building? Maybe that needs a dog's brain.
- Need something that can monitor a whole society? Then you need [a Vulcan's brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spock%27s_Brain).

Curiously, the idea of using brains as "AI" in stories is quite common. I linked you to "Spock's Brain," an episode of Star Trek TOS. There's also Anne McCaffrey's *The Ship Who Sang* series of books, the Cybermen of Doctor Who, any invocation of *Robocop,* which all kinda go back to the Frankenstein stories. When you think about it, "brain in a can" stories have been around for a very long time.

An old proverb says there's only nine stories in the universe and an infinite number of ways to tell those stories. Use brains, the perfect biological alternative to AI — just come up with a cool way to explain your version of it.

Answer (score 0):

As you gauge AI in your sentence like this - "... mechanical gods that evolved from advanced AI,.."

So in that sense we do not have artificial inteligence, what do we have are artificial neural networks and it really hard to make "mechanical gods" out of them, I mean it hard to make artificial human level idiots out of them, or animal level awareness / intellectual capabilities.

So if you think they are useful, and they probably are, they are incapable to become artificial gods, even advanced versions such as AlphaGo and similar, for reasons beyond the scope of the answer.
Can there be their biological equivalent - yes, and it could make sense to have such and it also will be incapable to become an overlord. Intelligence and size are not proportional, if we touch the subject of that they can grow.

If we talk really about intelligence, human level 80IQ and up, to overlord level, or their equivalents, systems like where agents can be as stupid as cocroaches, but their swarm intelligence is of above mentionend levels.

Sure there is subset of biological implementations for those - mean most prominent example are humans themselves, different swarm insects, fishes, and a good list of other animals.

The poblem, however, is fundamental, and it can't be solved just by changing medium for that intelligence from silicone and metall to carbon and water. If anything, such change my make things worse, because of direct competition for carbon and water stuff, and the fact that in star systems and in the universe there is more carbon and hydrogen, at this point in time, than heavy elements like metalls and such(so metall guys could be at disadvantage compared to carbon based life forms because of that, which also could be the reason to have biological stuf, better than one you use now). And nothing stops that superior biological intelligence to use metall and silicon constructions and intelligences as a tool for itself, if those are good for some reason, and presumubly as it is smarter it can keep those in check better than humans did, and maybe it does that for humans, that being the purpose of it.

There are safe ways to handle the situation, ants are an example they are a dead end - they can evolve and adapt, and they do, make complex enough constructions as if they have knowledge, travel and apply other relativel sofisticated strategies - quite certain they can be called pinnacle of isects intelligence which we have here on earth, ants and co. But they won't become a super intelligence, as they didn't in the last 100 million years. In their subjective time line, propagating 20times faster than humans it like if humans lived for 2 billion years, and actually more(because of their numbers) Imean their strategy is stuck - this is the kind of stability we may look for our intelligent machines, and it is relatively easy to achieve it, neural networks are somewhat an example of that.

It possible to have similar approaches made in metall and similar stuff. Making conditions, systems which will be stable and useful to humans.

And it not that easy to make something super smart, so it not likely to be some sort of discovery by accident. And it actually no that easy to be sneaky about smartness, because it requires more calculations and such so we can monitor stuff, and keep it under control.

3rd direction of keeping things in check, it nice to have an idea or knowledge, but it requires resources for its implementation, which are proportional to the scale of the task at hands. And some things do not change, like chemical reactions, energy required to make this or that - it does not care how smart one is.

So control over resources like matter(elements) and energy is one of the ways to keep balance or control. Sure you smarter and can do X 10 times more efficiently, but we have 20 times more of the stuff, and thus can make 2 times more of what you can do.

So answer is yes, but it also should be done right, and if mechanical stuff done right it also can be keept under control. If things are done wrong then it does not matter what it was, it will be a trainwreck anyway.

Does biological stuff have some advantages, sure, it closest thing we have to nanotechnology, energy efficienty is high in some cases. So as there are cases where it other way around.

So nothing that much wrong with biological stuff or AI's, especially if things are not extreame, but sure better reasons for it can "easily" be found.